# Restrict withholding taxes in MIRO by current PO type?

Tags: abap, s4hana, badi

The business is asking me that during `MIRO` for a vendor in the withholding taxes are coming the ones that have been setup in the Vendors. What they want is from all these Withholding taxes to keep only the ones that belongs to the specific Purchase Order (PO) type. For example we have a vendor and during `MIRO` the following `EH` taxes are coming 01, 04, 06, 07. But for the specific PO Type we want to display in the tab only 01 and 04.

I tried the BAdIs `MRM_WT_SPLIT_UPDATE` and `MRM_HEADER_CHECK` but nothing is happening.
[image]

I want to display only the first 2 lines, not the last 2 ones.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Our system is S/4HANA.

Thanks in advance
Elias